# Data migration is not happening properly to CosmosDB using data Migration tool

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am exporting document using "Sudio 3T" and it generates below JSON.

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5aa8bf0077bbfe296c1727de" }, "_t" : "DiscreteProperty", "Name" : "AHRI_bCertified"}

Next I using migration tool import JSON to Azure CosmosDB. Result is, it uploads but not viewing the document because it doesn't _id field.

Note: I am not providing anything in "Id Field" of target screen(CosmosDB).

[image]

Comment: can you provide the json file and what is the issue?

Comment: I mentioned the JSON content in answer. It is uploading to CosmosDB but when I am trying to see it throws error because document doesn't contain _id field.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps but did't reproduce your issue.Please refer to my details.

***sample .json file:***

```
[
    { 
        "_id" : { "$oid" : "5aa8bf0077bbfe296c1727de" }, 
        "_t" : "DiscreteProperty", 
        "Name" : "AHRI_bCertified"
    }
]
```

***target info:***

[image]

***import result:***

[image]

Comment: If you see my json closely, it doesn't have array. I need to add "[]". Secondly, is my migration tool doesn't support correctly to upload or issue with my cosmos DB account..

Comment: Can you please share the link where you downloaded the migration tool. Is there any setting to portal to upload documents with "_id".

Comment: @ManasKumar You could download the tool from this site :https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436

Comment: @ManasKumar Any progress now? Does my answer helps you?